# PHP Mail() : how to get more information regarding failure of sending mails using php mail().

Tags: php, email

If php mail() fails to send a mail, is there any way using which we can get to know what's the exact reason for failure.

Comment: all mail-servers have logging, the mail server log is usually a good place to start.

Answer (score 1):

From a quick look, I was not able to find any way to catch errors generated by `mail()`. The easiest way would be to use [error_get_last](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-get-last.php), to collect the last error that has occurred. However, you should do this once `mail()` returns `false`.

Another possible solution would be to [set_error_handler](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.set-error-handler.php) and when you send a mail, and then immediately remove the handler after you send the mail. Then, your error handler should be able to catch any errors/warnings/notices that has occured while sending the mail.

Using a library like [swiftmailer](http://swiftmailer.org/) would be much more flexible as it would allow you to catch its errors and exceptions easily.

If you are talking about errors on the receiving server, then you need to implement [VERP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Variable_envelope_return_path) or some sort of a bounce detection algorithm. [PHPMailer-BMH](http://sourceforge.net/projects/bmh/) may be useful in this case.

Answer (score 0):

My configuration uses sendmail and it outputs crash reports in the sendmail directory. Check your folders for error dumps.